# Configure Linux Kernel for ARM

Tags: kernel, arm

I want to configure kernel 2.6.30 for ARM CPU in a graphical environment (using Ubuntu 10.04). There is program called "qconf" which can do this easily, but I can't run it.

I've downloaded and installed "qconf" but it's not graphical (just terminal commands). Is there any GUI alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are compiling a kernel and want a graphical tool to review the configuration ?

Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglade2-dev
```

Then to use it you

```
make gconfig
```

[image: gconfig]

Comment: Thank you for responding,but "make gconfig" return's :No rule to make 'gconfig'.Should I use it (make gconfig) in specific folder?And how can I run this graphical tool or software?

Comment: you need to be in the same directory as the kernel source. Are you sure you know how to do this ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile  http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/kernel